# Get the length in characters of a PyGTK TextView

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a gtk TextView in a maximized window and I want to know how many characters a line can fit before you have to scroll.

Comment: Unless you're using a monospace font (which doesn't look good except for code;-), there's no single answer -- `i` is a narrow character, `m` is a wide one, so more `i`s will fit than `m`s in any given breadth of available space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if there is any way to do padding in TextBuffer.insert() akin to printf() in C / C++ or print("%5s" % (i)) in python?

Comment: no, not in `TextBuffer.insert()` itself, but of course you can use a formatted string as an argument: `buffer.insert(iter, '%5s' % i)`

Answer (score 0):

(Friendly reminder, please stop putting answers in the comments, people.)

To summarize:

It depends on the size of the TextView, size of the window, size of the font, and as Alex Martelli said, the particular font and the usage of letters..."i" is a narrow letter, "m" is a wide letter, thus you can fit more "i"s than you can "m"s in a given space.

So, in short, there is no way to know for sure.